# How to redirect the domain page to another one host?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have designed a dashboard page for monitoring databases also having two servers(different hosts), i need to redirect my dashboard page from one host to another one by checking whether mysql is reachable or not on current host, i have a php code to check the mysql available.

```
 <?php

         $host="189.168.81.50";
          $port="3306";
         $dbUsername="appuser";
        $dbPassword="Appuser";


        $host1="192.168.81.25";
        $port1="3306";
        $dbUsername1="appuser";
        $dbPassword1="Appuser";


      $link = mysql_connect($host.':'.$port, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
      $link1 = mysql_connect($host1.':'.$port1, $dbUsername1, $dbPassword1);

    if ($link) {

    echo "connection 1 successful";

      }

      if($link1) {

       echo "connection 2 successful";

       }

      ?>
```

here connection one is success then the page should `http://189.168.81.50/dashboard`but if connection two is suucess then it should be `http://192.168.81.25/dashboard` and intially consider now on in `http://189.168.81.50/dashboard`

Answer (score 2):

Just use :

```
header('Location:http://www.yahoo.com');
```

Comment: Or You can user redirect(); inbuilt function